# CP Embed Pods Frameworks - ARCHIVE FAILED in ionic capacitor project

Tags: ionic-framework, continuous-integration, capacitor

anyone are experience these issue? I would like to ask if you have any idea for these to resolve

Processing Info.plist

▸ Running script ‘[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks’

▸ Generating ‘App.app.dSYM’

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-azlyibamtvkrbhfwntgmcwffjqtw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/App.build/Script-9592DBEFFC6D2A0C8D5DEB22.sh (in target ‘App’ from project ‘App’)

(1 failure)

I tried to fix the [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks - ARCHIVE

Answer (score 5):

Add the "**-f**" switch to get the absolute link path as per the below image

More details [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123852)

[image]